# ¿Cómo crear una expresión regular que solo acepta caractéres alfabéticos, guiones y espacios con un mínimo de siete caracteres?

Tags: html5, frontend

Buenas tardes chicos,

Necesito de su apoyo, estoy haciendo una página que tiene un formulario y uno de los campos del formulario se nombro "Business Position", no requiere que se valide, pero se nos pide que que usemos el atributo **patern** y usemos una expresión regular que solo acepte "caracteres alfabéticos, guiones y espacios con un mínimo de siete caracteres".

Yo intente esto:

**input type="text" id="business-position" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{7}"**

Pero no entiendo que hacer para que acepte tambien guiones y espacios.

Saludos y buena tarde

Comment: Usa secuencia de escape para espacios y guiones: `pattern="[a-zA-Z\-\ ]{7}"`. Allí estoy incluyendo guiones: `\-` y espacios `\ `. Usando la barra invertida seguida del carácter que deseo escapar

Comment: Mauricio muchas gracias, es que todavía me falta experiencia en front end y aun siguo aprendiendo. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que los caracteres admitidos son:

- Alfabéticos: `[a-zA-Z]`
- Guion: `\-`
- Espacio: `\s`
- Y que los caracteres se repitan desde 7 a más veces `{7,}`

```css
input:valid {
    background-color: palegreen;
}

input:invalid {
    background-color: lightpink;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault()">
<input type="text" id="business-position" pattern="[a-zA-Z\-\s]{7,}$">

<input type="submit" value="enviar" onsubmit="return false" >
</form>
```

**¿El problema?**

El atributo `pattern` no funciona para los input vacíos, lo que ocasiona que se valide para 0 y 7 o más caracteres Tal como indica la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern#constraint_validation)

*(traducción automática)*

> **Si el valor de la entrada no es la cadena vacía** y el valor no coincide
> con toda la expresión regular, se produce una infracción de
> restricción notificada por la propiedad

Entonces, necesitamos usar el atributo `required` para cumplir todas las condiciones

```css
input:valid {
    background-color: palegreen;
}

input:invalid {
    background-color: lightpink;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault()">
<input type="text" id="business-position" pattern="[a-zA-Z\-\s]{7,}$" required>

<input type="submit" value="enviar" onsubmit="return false" >
</form>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Yussef, es que aún estoy aprendiendo en la escuela front end y en la documentación de mdn no me quedo muy claro esto de las expresiones regulares.

Te lo agradezco

Comment: @Muloki Ningún problema estimado, un placer haber podido ayudar con grano de arena. Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada si así te parece. Saludos

Comment: Y no podría pasar que alguien llene el campo con siete espacios, y luego un middleware decida hacer trim()  a los strings que recibe?

Comment: @ffflabs Yo creo que este problema es más un ejercicio académico que un problema "de la vida real"....que acepte 7 espacios seguidos (o guiones) no tiene sentido, ni en el cliente ni en el servidor.

Answer (score 1):

El patrón correcto sería así:

```
<input type="text" id="business-position" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]{7,}$" title="Letras, números, guiones y espacios; con un mínimo de siete caracteres" required>
```